# Convert a date string to a Unix timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have this date "Mon Mar 15 20:51:18 +0000 2010". How do i convert this date into a Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'time'
Time.parse("Mon Mar 15 20:51:18 +0000 2010").to_i
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call ".to_i" on your DateTime object

Comment: There is no `to_i` on `DateTime`, you have to go via `Time`, i.e. `.to_time.to_i`

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely use

```
require 'time'
Time.parse("Mon Mar 15 20:51:18 +0000 2010").to_i
```

Like user30997 and Zepplock said, however if you have non-standard time string, you might want to use the *chronic* library.

```
require 'chronic'
Chronic.parse('tomorrow').to_i
```

It makes input fields on websites really nice for the end user.