# Convert a string to type timestamp in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

I have the following string `2012-7-31 09:38:00.000000` which I want to convert to type timestamp (without time zone) in *PGadmin*. Which methods in ruby can get the job done?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451125/convert-a-date-string-to-a-unix-timestamp and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200825/convert-string-to-datetime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
DateTime.parse("2012-7-31 09:38:00.000000")

#output
Tue, 31 Jul 2012 09:38:00 +0000

DateTime.parse("2012-7-31 09:38:00.000000").to_i
#output is timestamp
1343727480
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Time.parse("2012-7-31 09:38:00.000000").to_i
```

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "time_to_display" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying at character 108
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.